# How resolve HTTP Error 500.19 on IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api2, iis-8.5

after update .net framework 4.5 to 4.5.2 in visual studio solution.. then my hosted web site/api stop working.

it is giving me below mention handler error.[image]

Answer (score 2):

After review lots of artical , i done lots of thing on IIS,

Like :

1. run->cmd
   "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i"
2. Remove Handler from web config file .
3. restart iis and etc . etc...

I got a solution , which help out me .I am sharing with you.

Just go to IIS Manager to edit those settings.

[image]

select Feature Delegation from the root of IIS:

[image]

Do sorting , then you will find some of having only, read permission.

make it read/write permission.

[image]

After update this .. try and run your application..

Thanks...